# Trying to automate a slideshow in javascript

Tags: javascript

Ive looked other questions similiar to my issue but ive been unable understand and resolve issue.

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
            var images  = new Array();
            images[0]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow0.jpg";
            images[1]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow1.jpg";
            images[2]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow2.jpg";
            images[3]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow3.jpg";
            var current = 0;


            function changeImage(inc) {
                current += inc;
                document.getElementById("target").src = images[Math.abs(current)%images.length];
                setTimeout("changeImage()",1000);
            }
```

Comment: Unable to resolve what issue?

Comment: Use the Javascript library W3.JS https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/default.asp

Comment: I just edited my post to use pure JS, check it, I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

## HTML Slideshow?

Well, look this https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_slideshow.asp

Use the Javascript library W3.JS
https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/default.asp

Or use pure JS

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't posted all of the relevant code, or you're missing something like:

```
changeImage(1);
```

To kick off your slideshow and get it started.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely not just use purely JavaScript for this.  Try and make sure your html is where the content is housed, your CSS is where majority of styling is, and then use you JS to make the interactivity and movement.  All that to say, kick the actual images out of there, leave them in html.  Then create a class in CSS for showing the image, then a class for hiding.  Then use you JavaScript to add/remove the classes.

Comment: I believe it is not a good idea to do this
In the future, you might need to add a new image, or delete an image inside the array.
If you do it in Javascript, you can easily add a new element to the array, but on the other hand, if you do this task by changing class, you need to add a new HTML tag every image.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Héctor Manuel Martinez Durán will solve the issue,

But if you still want to use pure Javascript, you can read my answer

1) Instead of using setTimeout, try to use setInterval (setTimeout will execute only once, but setInterval will execute until the page is closed)
2) You did not execute the function, you need to run the function with an argument inc

so the code will be:

```
var images  = new Array();
  images[0]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow0.jpg";
  images[1]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow1.jpg";
  images[2]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow2.jpg";
  images[3]   = "http://ed-moore.net/html/assets/slideshow3.jpg";
  var current = 0;

  function changeImage(inc) {
      current += inc;
      document.getElementById("target").src = images[Math.abs(current)%images.length];
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    changeImage(1);
  }, 1000);
```